# C# Networking Issue Multiple Processes

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

Whenever my client loses connection of the server, I have a re-connection loop which continuously looks for the server.

As this loop runs, it generates a process of conhost.exe and csc.exe every time it tries to connect until the computer slows to a halt.

Does anyone know what would create these processes?

So what happens, is anytime there is a failconnection or a loseconnection, I call Initialize. This should properly dispose all components and then reinitialize them all.

Initialize Method for NetworkInterface and TcpInterface:

```
 public void Initialize()
    {
        if (ni != null)
        {
            ni.Dispose();
            GC.Collect();
        }

        if (tcpInterface != null)
        {
            tcpInterface.Dispose();
        }

        tcpInterface = new TcpInterface();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
        {
            tcpInterface.Settings = new TcpSettings
            {
                RemoteIp = ipAddress,
                Port = _port,
                PacketDenotesLength = false
            };
        }

        tcpInterface.NewConnection += new TcpInterface.TcpNetworkStateEventHandler(tcpInterface_NewConnection);
        tcpInterface.FailConnection += new TcpInterface.ConnectionEventHandler(tcpInterface_FailConnection);
        tcpInterface.ReceivePacket += new TcpInterface.TcpInterfacePacketEventHandler(tcpInterface_ReceivePacket);
        tcpInterface.LoseConnection += new TcpInterface.TcpNetworkStateEventHandler(tcpInterface_LoseConnection);

        ni = new NetworkInterface<string, PacketInfo>();
        ni.Services.Register("TcpInterface", tcpInterface);

        ni.Initialize();
    }
```

Dipose for TcpInterface:

```
public void Dispose()
    {
        if (TcpClient != null)// && TcpClient.Connected)
        {
            if (TcpClient.Connected)
            {
                NetworkStream stream = TcpClient.GetStream();

                if (stream != null)
                {
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
            TcpClient.Close();
            TcpClient = null;
        }
        Buffer = null;
        BufferBuilder = null;
    }
```

Dispose for ni:

```
 public void Dispose()
    {
        Services.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: for multiple conhost read here http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2009/10/05/windows-7-windows-server-2008-r2-console-host.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

csc.exe is C# compiler.

do you use XmlSerializer for serlization/deserialization? if you didn't sgen'ed your assemblies, then XmlSerializer will start csc.exe and compile some code to temporary folder.

Another option, is using CodeDom in C#. the code then will compile using csc.exe.

Comment: I would bet it's XmlSerializers for web services.

Comment: I do not believe that there are any web services or XmlSerialization going on. This is a networking library for communications between two computers, basic Tcp or UDP.